# Is this a secure method for user authentication? If so, can it be simplified to reduce the total number of requests?

Tags: oauth, passport.js, koa, next.js

I've been digging around in Koa and had a setup which seemed to work fine. I then decided SSR would be beneficial and I'm struggling a bit with creating a method for authentication which is straightforward.

In essence the steps I am taking are:

1. User visits Next.JS served page.
2. User clicks "Login with facebook" and a request is sent to my Koa server at /auth/facebook
3. OAuth with passport occurs and a token is generated and stored for the user (either created then or updated)
4. A very short lived token is generated and the user is redirected to the Next.JS application with the short lived token in the URL.
5. Next.JS sends this short lived token to the Koa API and a real access token is returned and stored in a cookie.
6. This new access token is used for subsequent requests to the API.

This feels very complicated and I feel it might be possible to remove the short lived token step altogether.

From what I have read, it is not a good idea to use Next.JS for back-end API related logic which is why the auth happens on the Koa-API server and hence the need to pass a short lived token to get a real token.

Am I over-complicating this? Is there a simpler method that I'm just not seeing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit of fiddling around, I cut it down to only a few requests instead.

I moved Passport.js into a custom Next.JS server (using Koa) and set the callbacks to target Next. Then I verify the token on each request as it is now stored by Next.JS instead of with my API server, cutting out 4 and 5.